# need to copy data from one sheet to another depending on a value of the first sheet

Tags: excel, formula

i have never used excel except for in college and well that was a while ago, what i have is 3 sheets sheet 1 contains all user information sheet 2 is company information and sheet 3 is company member information,

now what i need to do is this,

i need to loop through sheet 1 column K and search for what is not "Individual" then i need the value of sheet 1 column A and put that in sheet 3 column C
i also need the index of the same row that does not equal "Individual" and use that to grab the value of sheet 2 column A and put that in sheet 3 column B

hopefully that makes sense and is actually possible and any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Needs sample data and expected results.  Difficult to follow with just a text description, and unclear if any proposed solution will be what you're looking for.  Additionally, please show your work.  What have you tried so far?  It vaguely sounds like [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: i have not tried anything cause i dont know anything about excel formulas, and i cant show you the records b/c there user records with personal information,

Comment: We don't need the exact data you're working with.  That's why I specifically asked for *sample* data.  Just some dummy data showing what you have, and what you're trying to get.  It's also fine to not know anything about excel formulas, but did you at least go to the vlookup page I linked?  Is vlookup an appropriate solution? If not, why not?  Sample data would go a long way towards getting us in the right direction.

Comment: Surely you can simply filter column k and copy and paste columns A and C, then use index match to pull the data into column B from sheet 2. You could then copy and paste as values if you don't want the formulas. `index(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5000,match(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$5000,C2,0),1)` you could use a formula like that in B2 on Sheet3 and auto fill down.